# Significant devotion of Gunaseela Maharishi

Tags: rishi, bhakti

What is the great achievement by this maharishi? How the God appeared before him and what the God asked him to do?

Answer (score 4):

**Gunaseela MahAtmiyam(குணசீல மஹாத்மியம்)**

Gunaseela Maharishi is the devout sishyA of ThAlpiya Maharishi(தால்பிய மஹரிஷி). Once ThAlpiya Maharishi along with his sishyAs went to the Himalayas to worship Vyasa then took Ganga snAnam and snAnam in other holy waters. On their return, they stopped at ThiruVenkatamalai (திருவேங்கடமலை) to worship ThiruVEnkatamUdayAn(திருவேங்கடமுடையான்) or Perumaal Venkateswara.

**Gunaseela Maharishi felt inseparable devotion to Perumaal and beseeched Perumaal to come with them. On hearing this devout Bhakta of his, Perumaal said that he had committed to grace darshan onto devotees from Thirumalai till the end of the current Kalpa and told Gunaseela Maharishi to perform Tapasya upon returning to the Ashram, by receiving the right notion from his GuruNatha ThAlpiyar to undertake the same, assuring Gunaseelar that his intention will be duly fulfilled.**

Gunaseelar then told his GuruNathar about this, to which ThAlpiyar responded, "It is well known that future events are foretold in the Puranams. **In that way it is known that as a result of your Tapasya, SriVaikunthaVaasudeva will rise in your Ashram located in the North bank of Cauvery as DivyaMangalaVigrahaSwaroopan with ThiruNaamam of Sri Prasanna Venkatesan**(ஸ்ரீ பிரஸன்ன வேங்கடேசன்) **along with Sri Devi ThAyAr gracing Devotees with their presence and granting the bhaktas' wishes till the end of the current Kalpa**"(ஸ்ரீதேவியுடன் ஸ்ரீ பிரஸன்ன வேங்கடேசன் என்ற திருநாமத்துடன் இந்த கல்பம் முடியும் வரை திவ்யமங்கள விக்ரஹ ஸ்வருபனாய் எழுந்தளியிருந்து). Having said so, ThAlpiya Maharishi blessed Gunaseelar.

Gunaseela Maharishi upon returning to his Ashram, after duly bathing in the river Cauvery, undertook steadfast Tapasya, meditating with his Manas one-pointed on SriVaikunthaVaasudevar(ஸ்ரீ வைகுண்ட வாஸுதேவனை மனதில் தியானம் செய்து தவம் இயற்றலானர்). **His Tapasya undeterrable - amidst PanchAgni in the summer, donning wet vasthram in Winter, Standing in Water during Monsoon. Devas became aware of it and became afraid. Indra, fearing that his post might be usurped, launched a host of attacks with Thunder, Rain, Storm, Lightning and other numerous means attempted to shatter Gunaseelar's Tapasya in vain.**

The Devas flabbergasted by defeat approached Lord Brahma and enquired onto the reason for Gunaseelar's Tapasya. Brahma immediately saw with the power of his Jnana Dhrishti that Gunaseelar, with the express intent of being graced by Perumaal in his Ashram, was meditating unshaken on SriVaikunthaVaasudeva. Thus, having heard from Brahma that they had nothing to fear, the Devas paid respect to Lord Brahma and returned to their abode. Such is the greatness of Gunaseela Maharishi's meditation on Perumaal.

In due time, EmPerumaal SriVaikunthaVaasudevar along with SriLakshmi ThAyAr set out on VedaSwaRoopan GarudAzhwan to Gunaseela Maharishi's Ashram to grace him who had taken Perumaal himself as his only refuge and meditated unwaveringly.

Knowing thus, that Perumaal and ThAyAr are arriving from Vaikuntham, Brahma & Saraswati, Siva & Parvati, Devis & Devas, Sanatkumara Munis, Sage Naradar, Thumburu & GandharvAs, Kinnargal & Kimpurushargal, Yakshas, Sakhyas, SAranAs & others and ThAlpiyar & his Sishyas arrived to Gunaseela Maharishi's Ashram and awaited eagerly Perumaal & ThAyAr's Arrival.

On Arrival, EmPerumaal grants glorious Darshan to Gunaseelar(which is described in exquisite detail [here](http://gunaseelamtemple.com/aboutus.html)) and grants Maharishi Gunaseelar a boon - through which he asks for SrimanNarayana to grace all his devotees and grant their wishes by taking Nitya Vaasam at his Ashram till the end of the Kalpa. Perumaal obliges Gunaseelar's wishes as Sri Prassana Venkatesan carrying Lakshmi ThAyAr in his chest appearing with Shanka, Chakra, VaradaHastham & KadiHastham(கலியுக தெய்வமாய்த் திகழ ஸ்ரீ பிரஸன்ன வேங்கடேசனாக திவ்யமங்கள விக்ரஹஸ்வரூபனாய் சங்கு சக்கரம் வரதஹஸ்தம் கடிஹஸ்தம் உடையவராய், திருமார்பில் இலக்குமியைத் தாங்கி நின்ற திருகோலத்தில் காட்சியளித்தார்).

[image: Gunaseelam-Sri-Prasanna-Venkatesa-Perumaal]

Source: [Official Temple site](http://gunaseelamtemple.com/index.html)

Comment: ---Albeit you gave the answer from temple website, many more incidences of gunaseela maharishi were there like cow pouring milk on the pambu putru wherein Prasanna venketeswara was inside the pambu puttru etc. Drive deep to discover the fitting answer.

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan These stories you mention regarding Sri Prasanna Venkateswara happens after Gunaseela Maharishi has left the corporeal realm - the pambu putru story in particular is about the rediscovery of Sri Prasanna Venkateswara by a latter day king. Moreover, I've covered both the questions you've asked in as much detail as possible. If you feel i've answered your question, consider accepting the answer.

Comment: @ Lakshmi Narayanan-- It has happened when gunaseela maharishi was doing penance, Gunaseelar himself observed the miracle. You have given part answer how you expect to accept your answer.

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan "It has happened when gunaseela maharishi was doing penance, Gunaseelar himself observed the miracle" What is your source for this? I've visited the temple many times and the story is beautifully shown inside the temple in the form of paintings. This corroborates my account from the temple website as well. Thus, it is not as you say a partial answer.

Comment: Narayanan --See the paintings on the left side wall when you go for pradakshinam. I think you might have observed but forgot to put in your answer. My kula devatha is Prasanna vankatachalapathy swamy only and previous month may 6 2017 also I went to the temple.

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan Yes, I'm referring to the same paintings as well!

Comment: But you have not put that as one of the answers.

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59971/discussion-between-lakshmi-narayanan-and-parthasarathy-raghavan).